# Sound not working after installing PCI video card and then removing it

Tags: sound, soundcard

I am running 11.10 on a HP/Compaq Presario sr1010z, and the video/audio was working fine with whatever was in the machine already.  Then I installed a new video card (PCI/nVidia), which disabled the audio/video on the old one automatically.  But that card didn't work out too well so I removed it.

Now the video is back to normal, but the audio is gone.

I have tried the following:

1. In BIOS, set audio to on/enable rather than Auto
2. Looked for hardware in System Settings > Sound, but nothing shows up there
3. But when I run the sysinfo utility, I get the description of the audio controller

When I do a `sudo aplay -l`, I get:

```
aplay: device_list:240: no soundcards found...
```

And then when I do a `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`, I get the following:

```
00:02.7 Multimedia audio controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS7012 AC'97 Sound Controller (rev a0)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a05
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 5
    I/O ports at a000 [size=256]
    I/O ports at a400 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:03.0 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran the Ubuntu CD to repair installation and that fixed the issue.